# "Sides" or "Aspects" of video games

Tags: usage

Are these sentences interchangeable?

> What do you think are the *best/good/bad/worst* **sides** of playing video games?
>
> What do you think are the *best/good/bad/worst* **aspects** of playing video games?

Comment: Perhaps "sides" means the ***role*** you take in the game, and "aspects" means how it affects the person who ***plays*** the game.

Comment: Side meaning aspect is usually in the singular and often refers to people: His worst side was his temper.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks. Can't I use "sides" here for meaning how it affects the person who plays the game? And do you agree with what Lambie said?

Comment: My first comment was provocative, as if you had written "What do you think is the best/good/bad/worst side in video games?" As written, your second sentence is better, but perhaps you could use "effects" instead of "aspects", depending on the intention of the question.

Comment: To answer your stated question: No, they're not 100% interchangeable. Along a spectrum there is a point of intersection common to the two words, but that connection is weak at best and certainly not the only one available. And *sides* is by no means the best synonym for *aspects* you could find.

Comment: I'd choose *part/thing* as a *general way* to tell that.